# CSS Focus animation repeats

Tags: css, focus

Every time when I change my browser tab, the focus animation repeats. I want to prevent this. Is there any way to do that? Thanks for any help.

Here's the demo: http://output.jsbin.com/vidapu

```
<div id="box" tabindex="0">
Click me...

<div id="box-dropdown">...and now switch your browser tab</div>
```

Comment: The focus is being restored when you switch the tabs, hence the animation plays again. If you want to show another box after clicking on the first one, just add onClick event on the first box and remove the `hidden` class from the hidden box by default.

Comment: I will try it, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When you change tabs, you are no longer "focused" on that element. When you change back, the focus state is restored. The only way to prevent this behavior is to trigger the animation on something other than focus.
If you want it to be triggered on click, you should use a JavaScript click event.

Initially set `display: none;` on the animated box, and then change it to `display: block;` when the button is clicked.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to avoid the JavaScript, but thank you for the help anyways!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid JavaScript? It exists for a reason :)